# Google auth with .Net web api

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, google-oauth

I want to implement google auth in server without the frontend. I cannot understand how I will read the response from google after redirection to google.

I was expecting an response with all the data from the user.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

In  order to access private user data you must have their consent to access that data.  Consent is granted though the use of the Oauth2 consent form.

[image]

This consent form must be displayed in a web browser.

## installed app.

If your application is on a server and the user is logged into the server via shell or command line, you could show the user a consent URL that they can then copy and paste into a web browser on their machine.

## web app

If you are creating a web application then you may want to have a look at the [web-applications-asp.net-core-3](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3) example.  Which shows how to requst authorization of the user in a web application.

```
/// <summary>
/// Lists the authenticated user's Google Drive files.
/// Specifying the <see cref="GoogleScopedAuthorizeAttribute"> will guarantee that the code
/// executes only if the user is authenticated and has granted the scope specified in the attribute
/// to this application.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="auth">The Google authorization provider.
/// This can also be injected on the controller constructor.</param>
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly)]
public async Task<IActionResult> DriveFileList([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });
    var files = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
    var fileNames = files.Files.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    return View(fileNames);
}
```